# Get src value of image in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a **directive** with an **isolated scope** on my page, now inside this directive i **dynamically set the src attribute** of the **img** with **ng-src**, however i now want to get that **src** value outside of the isolated scope, in my parent controller, i would like to know how to do it.  This is just an example of what i want to do:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <directive action=""></directive>
</div>
```

This is the directive's html:

```
<img ng-src="{{ src }}" id="img-preview"/>
```

I want to be able to **get** the value of **ng-src** from **inside** my **ParentController** despite the fact that my **directive** uses an **isolated scope**, is that possible and if so then how do i do it?

**Edit:** The directive here is a directive for handling images, so all the uploads etc are done from within the directives controller, now i want to get the value returned from the server in my ParentController from the directive's controller.

Comment: means you want to pass src from controller..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ngLover is correct.  Pass it into your directive from the parent.

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <directive action="" action-img-src="imgSrc"></directive>
</div>
```

Then in your directive:

```
<img ng-src="{{ actionImgSrc }}" id="img-preview"/>
```

Comment: Actually the directive handles the src of the image, meaning the image src is generated from WITHIN the directive so i can't pass it to it from the parent.

Comment: but if you have direct binding **=actionImgSrc**, then the position of this in memory is in the same place for parent and child. That mean the value is shared. So if you change it in children, value will be change for parent too

Comment: @user3718908 Why not? You can double bind values.

Comment: Correct, 2 way data binding

Comment: I am confused so are you saying even if i set the value from inside the directive i can still access it from inside the Parent controller like so: actionImgSrc?

Comment: Yes. If you are having trouble, post a plunk or fiddle.

Comment: Well based on what you said, i tried and tried and finally got what i want, it works now so thanks. :D